# Inserir caractere na última posição do cursor dentro do input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
$('#mais').click(function(){
  $('#console').val($('#console').val() +"+");
});

$('#menos').click(function(){
  $('#console').val($('#console').val() +"-");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="console" type="text">
<button id="mais">+</button>
<button id="menos">-</button>
```

Nesse código consigo inserir os caracteres no final do *input* sempre que clico nos botões correspondentes, mas como faço para inserir na última posição do cursor de texto dentro do *input*?

Exemplo:

1. Digitei o texto:
  ```
  maismais
  ```
2. Coloquei o cursor de texto no meio do texto:
  ```
  mais|mais
  ```
3. Cliquei no botão <kbd>-</kbd>, gostaria que o resultado fosse esse:
  ```
  mais-mais
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este script faz o que propõe. Ele insere o sinal do botão clicado e mantém o cursor focado no campo.

**Sugiro** que simplifique o código: em vez de usar duas funções para cada botão, use apenas uma:

```
$('#mais, #menos').click(function(e){
   insereSinal('#console', e.target.textContent);
});
```

```js
$('#mais, #menos').click(function(e){
   insereSinal('#console', e.target.textContent);
});

function insereSinal(cId, sinal){
   var cam = $(cId)[0];
   var cvl = $(cam).val();
   var cps = cam.selectionStart;
   var ini = cvl.substring(0, cps);
   var fim = cvl.substring(cps, cvl.length);
   $(cam).val(ini+sinal+fim);
   cps += sinal.length;
   cam.selectionStart = cam.selectionEnd = cps;
   cam.focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="console" type="text">
<button id="mais">+</button>
<button id="menos">-</button>
```

Se quiser a função comprimida:

```
$('#mais,#menos').click(function(e){insereSinal('#console',e.target.textContent);});
function insereSinal(cId,sinal){var cam=$(cId)[0];var cvl=$(cam).val();
var cps=cam.selectionStart;var ini=cvl.substring(0,cps);
var fim=cvl.substring(cps,cvl.length);$(cam).val(ini+sinal+fim);
cps+=sinal.length;cam.selectionStart=cam.selectionEnd=cps;cam.focus();}
```

**Compatibilidade:** IE9+, Edge, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera

**Fonte:** [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064139/1377664) (com adaptações e considerável redução de código)

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Assim funcionou!

```js
var element = $('#console');

$('#mais').click(function(){
 addChar('+', element);
});

$('#menos').click(function(){
 addChar('-', element);
});
 
function addChar(c, el) {
  var text = el.val();
  var pos = el[0].selectionStart;  // posição do cursor
  
  // insere o caracter
  el.val(text.substring(0, pos) + c + text.substring(pos));
  
  // voltar para o input
  el.focus();
  
  // posicionar o cursor na ultima posição
  el[0].selectionStart = pos + 1;
  el[0].selectionEnd = pos + 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="console" type="text">
<button id="mais">+</button>
<button id="menos">-</button>
```

Adaptado de https://stackoverflow.com/a/15977052/5789135

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/142238)

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Para ficar melhor teria como explicar sua resposta ?

Answer (score 1):

Esta função javascript permitirá inserir facilmente texto em um input onde o cursor estiver.

Neste caso o sinal `+` ou `-` no onclick dos botões

```
onclick="inserirSinal('console', '-')
```

ou

```
onclick="inserirSinal('console', '+')
```

```js
function inserirSinal(inputId, text) {
  var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
  if (!input) { return; }
  var scrollPos = input.scrollTop;
  var strPos = 0;
  var br = ((input.selectionStart || input.selectionStart == '0') ? "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false ) );
  if (br == "ie") {
    input.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart ('character', -input.value.length);
    strPos = range.text.length;
  } else if (br == "ff") {
    strPos = input.selectionStart;
  }

  var front = (input.value).substring(0, strPos);
  var back = (input.value).substring(strPos, input.value.length);
  input.value = front + text + back;
  strPos = strPos + text.length;
  if (br == "ie") {
    input.focus();
    var ieRange = document.selection.createRange();
    ieRange.moveStart ('character', -input.value.length);
    ieRange.moveStart ('character', strPos);
    ieRange.moveEnd ('character', 0);
    ieRange.select();
  } else if (br == "ff") {
    input.selectionStart = strPos;
    input.selectionEnd = strPos;
    input.focus();
  }

  input.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="console" type="text" value="maismais">
<button id="mais" onclick="inserirSinal('console', '-');return false;">-</a>
<button id="menos" onclick="inserirSinal('console', '+');return false;">+</a>
```

> Firefox, IE7, Opera, Safari e Chrome.

[Créditos](http://web.archive.org/web/20110102112946/http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/425/how-to-insert-text-into-a-textarea-where-the-cursor-is/)